# Xev doesnt recognize the down key

Tags: linux

I accidentally unbound my downkey. Now my system wont recognize it.

Xev prints out

> FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>      mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>   
>   FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>      mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor
>   
>   KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
>      keys:  2 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
>             0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

showkey -a dumps nothing when i press down.

> $ showkey -s 
>   $ 0xe0 0x50 0xe0 0xd0
>   $ showkey
>   $ keycode 108

I know xev would tell me down's keycode is 116.

What I am to do with this information I dont know but this is possible to fix I swear.

Also when I run dumpkeys "keycode 108 = Down" and thats it.
while next says

keycode 109 = Next 
shift keycode 109 = Scroll_Forward

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so the problem is LXDE (my desktop environment) had a keyboard shortcut for down bound to nothing. Deleted it and all was fixed.